# What is the active voice of the given sentence?

Tags: grammar, active-voice

> The concentration of harmful gases get increased in the air slowly.

What is the active voice of this sentence?

Comment: Do you have any additional context? It's difficult to make some sentences active if you don't know who or what is causing the change... as is the case here.

Comment: The concentration increases...      through some agency.  Whatever that agency is would become the subject of the sentence. For example, a defective exhaust system increases the concentration of harmful gases in the passenger area of a car.

Comment: In the passive sentence, "get" should be "gets" to agree with "concentration".

Comment: The sentence is not grammatical. Therefore, the question is irrelevant. x increases slowly. Get increased is wrong.

Comment: @Lambie Actually, "get" is another verb that can form the passive voice. It's usually understood to be less formal than "be".

Comment: @Ben Kovitxz - As a written sentence, it does not fly. One simply would not say or write /get increased/ here. Or /be increased/ either. The X of Y increases slowly in the air. It either increases or does not increase. The temperature in the oven is increased with the thermostat. That yes for be. But still no get. He got cold in the rain. The temperature got hot in the room. Get increase is not grammatical. Period. In any case, this is not a passive sentence. So until the sentence is fixed, there is no question.

Comment: @Lambie Did you read that in a grammar book? (They're often mistaken.) It's [not true](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22gets+increased%22%20physics&rls=en&tbm=bks).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The concentration of harmful gases in the air **increases** slowly.

Technically, this is not active voice, since **increases** here is used intransitively, that is, without a direct object. Technically, only transitive verbs are said to be in the active voice, but this is a distinction mainly of interest to grammarians (and people who make exams). For ordinary writing, this rewording is fine because it avoids the clumsiness of the passive version.

If you want to make the concentration of the harmful gases the object of the verb **increases**, then you'll need a noun to indicate the *agent* that is causing the concentration to increase. The agent will be the subject of the sentence in the active voice. Since you didn't tell us the agent in your question, I'll just make one up:

> **Satan's evil room freshener** slowly **increases** the concentration of harmful gases in the air.

You could move "slowly" to the end of the sentence to give it more emphasis.

<sup>If you don't know what a room freshener is, see [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22room+freshener%22&rls=en&tbm=shop).</sup>